# Want to implement ICEFaces in Sun One 7 Web Server

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, icefaces

I want to implement the JSF on Sun One Web Server 7.0. I repetitively got the exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet.(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:136)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet$3.newServer(MainServlet.java:87)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.checkSession(SessionDispatcher.java:86)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:45)

How to solve the issue?

Comment: which icefaces version is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ick, that's an ancient server! It's from 2003 and it supports at highest the legacy Servlet 2.3 / JSP 1.2. If you want to run JSF on it, you can use at highest JSF 1.1. JSF 1.2 and newer won't work on Servlet 2.3. Most of the component library packs you download nowadays includes JSF 1.2 or even 2.0. You'll need to downgrade that as well with a copy from the archive of http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net. Maybe something more needs to be taken into account, but that may depend on the exact IceFaces version.

Did you consider upgrading the server? I would warmly recommend it. Servlet 2.3 and JSF 1.1 are at end of life. You ain't going to get any support on them anymore.

Comment: Hi BalusC,

I remember you long back helped me to answer JSF questions in the Sun Forums. I reda your blog at balusc.blogspot.com/. Thank you for the advice.
Our client recommendation is to use the Sun One Web Server 7.0. We have already in the production Sun One 6.1 & application working fine in that application.

Now, I have to upgrade to Sun One 7.0 and deploy the application. It looks like the problem with the JSF versions or JSR files in the server.

Can you give me some ideas on the root cause of the problem.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Ice Faces Version is 1.8.2